# How can I emulate the signal sent by a PC sync cable to a Flash from an embedded computing board?

Tags: switches, signal, embedded, wire, synchronization

I have a speedlight multispectral flash (KV-FL1) with a PC sync cable that essentially sends an electrical signal when a camera's shutter opens to tell it to fire. PC sync is a Prontour-Compour synchronization cable meant for a camera and flash serial connection to trigger the flash in a synchronized manner with a camera.

I wish to use this electrical signal sent to the PC Sync cable from any embedded computing board (such as a raspberry pi or so) and trigger this flash remotely via an equivalent electrical signal to it.

I am not sure if this is possible but I spoke to the contact team at Kolari Vision and they suggested this would be the way to go:
"If you are ok with wiring, why not just wire directly to the sync port on the flash? I believe these are a simple on/off type switch that you would be able to power with PC or microcontroller."

I hope someone has some advice here :)

Comment: We (or you) would need to know the specifications of the interface, what are the properties of the input device to trigger it, or the output device sending the trigger signal to emulate it. These are cameras so the interface could just be "short these two wires together" but we don't know exactly.